# Laravel 5.1 set environment dynamically

Tags: laravel-5.1

I am using Laravel 5.1 in my application.
I want to create different config for different environment as we create in laravel 4.2.

In [Laravel 4.2](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/configuration#environment-configuration) we can create different environment config by creating a folder within the config directory that matches the environment name.

How can i do this in laravel5.1.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this package called "[laravel-5-cascading-config](https://github.com/phanan/cascading-config)"

**Features :**

- Laravel-4 style cascading config
- Nested configuration is fully supported

From [laravel5.1 docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1#environment-configuration)

> If you are developing with a team, you may wish to continue including
>   a **.env.example** file with your application. By **putting place-holder
>   values in the example configuration file**, other developers on your
>   team can clearly see which environment variables are needed to run
>   your application.